# Angular assign piped array to variable

Tags: angular

I've got some piece of code:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let article of articles
    | tableFilter: { id: searchResult, title: searchResult, author: searchResult }
    | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse
    | paginate: config"
      (change)="updateCollectionSize()">...</tr>
```

My question is quite straightforward. How to assign articles array to the new variable after all of the pipes are performed?

Comment: [You shouldn't use filtering & ordering pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe). Furthermore, pipes are used to **display** modified data : in the template, they don't change the variable value. If you want to change the variable value, you'll have to do it in your component TS code (which is great, because as said, you're not supposed to use filtering & ordering pipes, so you should order & filter in your component too)

Comment: thank you, could you leave here any tutorial about filtering and ordering in a component?

Comment: Exact same thing as the pipe, except that you put the function into the component !

Comment: should I call that filtering pipe on the search input keypress ?

Comment: Depends, there are several ways of doing so : observable, getter, on event ... Easiest would be the getter I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the modified list as a variable in your template, then you can do it like so:

```
 <div *ngIf="articles
    | tableFilter: { id: searchResult, title: searchResult, author: searchResult }
    | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse
    | paginate: config 
    as filteredArticles">

    <tr *ngFor="let article of filteredArticles">...</tr>
  </div>
```

Basically, just wrap everything in an ngIf and use 'as' (or the 'let' keyword) to declare a template variable containing the filtered articles.

That said, as has already been said in the comments by @trichetriche, you should probably be doing this kind of thing in your Typescript. I can't help you there without knowing more about the data structure and how you're trying to modify it.